# Given a fair four-sided die, let $Y$ equal the number of rolls needed to observe each face at least once.

Tags: probability-theory

> Argue that $Y=X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4$, where $X_i$ has a geometric distribution with $p_i = (5-i)/4, i=1,2,3,4$ and $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ are independent.

I know that $M_Y(t) = (M_X(t))^4$ but I can't see a clear path to the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $X_1$ is the number of rolls until you see one face (which is always 1).
$X_2$ is the number of rolls after that until you see a second face...

BTW, since $X_i$ have different distributions, there's no such thing as $M_X(t)$.  You mean $M_Y(t) = M_{X_1}(t) \ldots M_{X_4}(t)$.

Comment: Ok so each geometric distribution has a different probability. To observe each face we have $1 * \frac{3}{4} * \frac{2}{4} * \frac{1}{4}$ but I am still not sure how to show this works.

Comment: The first roll shows you one face.  Once you have seen one face, each roll has probability $1/4$ of showing you the face you already saw, and $3/4$ of showing you a new face.  So $X_2$ is geometric with success probability $3/4$.  Once you have seen two faces, each roll has probability $2/4$ of showing you one of the two faces you already saw, and $2/4$ of showing you a new face.  So $X_3$, the number of additional rolls you need to see a third face once you've seen two, is geometric with success probability $2/4$. And similarly $X_4$ is geometric with success probability $1/4$.

Comment: Thanks I believe I have a clear path now.